# Matlab - adding circle to every frame of movie

Tags: matlab, geometry, imread

I want to add a circle around a particle moving in a movie. I give in the coordinates of the particle for every frame (Variable `Traj`). However the following code only draws a solid rectangle on top of my particle for every frame. Any suggestions?

```
function movie = AurelieCreateMovie3(Filename, Traj)
    L = 369;
    color = [1:3];
    R = 7;
    info = imfinfo(Filename);
    W = info.Width;
    H = info.Height;

    movie = uint8(zeros(H,W,3,L)); 

    frame = Traj(:,1); 
    x = round(Traj(:,2));
    y = round(Traj(:,3));
    L = length(x); %length of this track
    dt = 0:0.01:2*pi;

    for k = 1:L
        movie(:,:,:,k) = imread(Filename,frame(k));    
        x_circle = R.* cos(dt) + x(k);
        y_circle = R.* sin(dt) + y(k);
        movie(round(y_circle), round(x_circle), color, k) = 255;
    end

    mov = immovie(movie);
    movie2avi(mov, 'moviefinal', 'compression', 'None', 'fps', 23);
    implay(mov);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When assigning values with `matrix(rows, columns) = value`, MATLAB assigns *every permutation* of the elements in `rows` and `columns` rather than just assigning the pair-wise combination of the two. You'll instead want to convert to a linear index using `sub2ind`

```
M = reshape(movie(:,:,:,k), [], size(movie, 3));
inds = sub2ind(size(M(:,:)), round(y_circle), round(x_circle));
M(inds,:) = 255;
movie(:,:,:,k) = M;
```

Comment: If I add your code istead of "movie(round(y_circle), round(x_circle), color, k) = 255;" it gives me the error: Error using sub2ind Out of range subscript

Comment: @user6275697 Sorry I missed where you were indexing into a 4D matrix. I've updated it to work in that case.